# What is "cflow" in ipfix？

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, ipfix

I am learning ipfix and found a cmd like this:

```
tshark -r ipfix.cap -n -d udp.port==4379，cflow -O cflow
```

What does the `cflow` part mean here?

I was also told to filter cflow if I use Wireshark in Windows.

Comment: You have found a command where? You were told by whom? In short, this lacks details...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  thanks i have known the answer, cflow means Cisco flow.

Comment: yes I know that, but I was asking about your command since its form was strange to me. If you have the answer,please post it yourself, and validate it so that it will close the question.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek it's from VMware nsx. I learned how to configure ipfix in nsx and a friend told me i can use those command to collect traffic in Linux. Or collect traffic in windows by filter cflow.

Comment: I know `tshark` I just do not see how your command can work. Anyway as I said please post your answer if you have it (as an answer, not as a comment) and accept it so that the question does not remain open.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cflow means Cisco flow. If i can collect some data through that command then tshark works.